# How can I get json array values in result using the new tsql json from server 2016?

Tags: arrays, sql-server, json, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a simple json with an array inside.

```
{
  "state": "Succeeded",
  "ip": [
    "137.117.198.99","137.117.198.100"
  ]  
}
```

I want to bring it into a tsql result from a simple sql. The result should look like a simple master detail relation.

I would expect something like:

```
state        ip
Succeeded    137.117.198.99
Succeeded    137.117.198.100
```

I tried it with tsql json from 2016 and cross apply like:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) =  '{
  "state": "Succeeded",
  "ip": [
    "137.117.198.99","137.117.198.100"
  ]  
}';

select
    network.[state], 
    ips.ip
from  openjson (@json)
with
(
    [state] nvarchar(100),
    ip nvarchar(max) as json
)
as network
cross apply openjson (network.ip)
with
(
    ip nvarchar(100)
) as ips
;
```

The result seems to go into the right direction (2 lines but the values from array is `null`), but with the array I'm not able to map the values.

Does anybody run into the same situation and know the solution?

thanks dietmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is almost exact, I think that you just need to remove the second `with` clause (since there is no `ip` field in your inner array) and select the `value` column from `ips` instead of `ip`:

```sql
declare @json nvarchar(max) =  '{
  "state": "Succeeded",
  "ip": [
    "137.117.198.99","137.117.198.100"
  ]  
}';

select
    network.[state], 
    ips.value as ip
from  openjson (@json)
with
(
    [state] nvarchar(100),
    ip nvarchar(max) as json
)
as network
cross apply openjson (network.ip)
as ips
;
```

Here is the output of this command:

[image]